# Linux Mint KDE 16 - Copy, cut & paste keyboard shortcuts don't work at dol

Tags: linux, linux-mint, kde

Completely weird problem here. The primary keyboard shortcuts don't work. The secondary DO work.
I can also copy & paste using mouse but who does that???

The primary (CTRL+C/X/V) are left at the defaults and don't work.

I have a shortcut for a show desktop widget set to META + D, that doesn't work either.
Copy & pasting works on Chromium, but not on Kate text editor.

Any ideas???

Comment: Bump? Anyone???

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is SO weird.
I had 2 layout languages. Russian was the default (I'm learning the language and for the on screen keyboard to work, I need to keep it as default).
Latin american Spanish, the secondary.

Most of the time I use it in Spanish.
So, the error was present when using it in Spanish.

I just had the crazy idea that maybe it was using the keys in Russian for the system commands.
I deleted Russian and now it's working!!!

Should I report a bug? I mean, if the text is entered in a language but the system commands in other, it sounds like a bug to me, it drove me completely crazy!